# How to calculate the probability of this modified birthday paradox?

Tags: probability

How to calculate the probability of exactly m people in a group of n people having a birthday on the same **fixed** date?

Standard bp assumptions apply - each day of the year is equally probable for a birthday, a year always has 365 days, etc.

Simple case 1 - the probability of 1 person in a group of 1 having a birthday on March 3.

Probability = Number of desired outcomes / Number of possible outcomes
            = 1 / 365.

Simple case 2 - the probability of both people in a group of 2 having a birthday on March 3.

For independent events A and B: P(A and B )= P(A)⋅P(B)

Probability = ( 1 / 365 )⋅( 1 / 365 )
            = 1 / 133225

Simple case 3 - the probability of at least 1 person in a group of 2 having a birthday on March 3.

Possible outcomes (Person #1 birthday , Person #2 birthday)= {(01 Jan, 01 Jan), (01 Jan, 02 Jan)...(01 Jan, 31 Dec), (02 Jan, 01 Jan)...(31 Dec, 31 Dec)}

Number of possible outcomes = 365 ^ 2
                            = 133225

Desired outcomes (Person #1 birthday , Person #2 birthday) = { (03 Mar, 01 Jan), (03 Mar, 02 Jan)...(03 Mar, 03 Mar)...(03 Mar, 31 Dec), (01 Jan, 03 Mar)...(02 Mar, 03 Mar), (04 Mar, 03 Mar)...(31 Dec, 03 Mar)}

Number of desired outcomes = 2⋅365 - 1
                           = 729

Probability = Number of desired outcomes / Number of possible outcomes
            = 729 / 133225.

Simple case 4 - the probability of exactly 1 person in a group of 2 having a birthday on March 3.

Possible outcomes = same as Simple case 3

Number of possible outcomes = 133225

Desired outcomes = Same as Simple case 3 excluding (03 Mar, 03 Mar)

Number of desired outcomes = 729 - 1
                           = 728

Probability = Number of desired outcomes / Number of possible outcomes
            = 728 / 133225.

General case - the probability of exactly m people in a group of n having a birthday on a fixed date.

Number of possible outcomes = 365 ^ n

How can I calculate the number desired outcomes? Is there a better strategy?

-Shane

Comment: The number of people with birthday on the given date is binomial distributed with parameters $n$ and $\frac{1}{365}$ with the usual assumptions (no $29th$ February and equal probabilities for all the other days to be the birthday).

Comment: There are ${n\choose m}$ to choose the $m$ people who will have the desired birthday.  Can you continue from here?

Comment: Please use $\LaTeX$: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: @Peter, thanks for the hint - I will research binomial distributions

Comment: @ saulspatz I am surprised that the number of possible birthdays (normally 365) does not enter your calculation.

Comment: Binomial Probability - the probability of exactly m successes on n repeated trials where p is the probability of success on an individual trial is nCm⋅p^m⋅(1−p)^n−m 

where the binomial coefficient nCm (read as "n choose m") is n!/(m!(n-m)!). In this case p = 1/365